# Localization of mobile apps

Tags: iphone, android, localization, internationalization

we have an app for iPhone and Android. And we would like to internationalize this app.

Are there some good ways / strategies to manage text resources for both plattforms - android and iPhone, which you use?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since usually translators like to have their texts in excel sheets, you basically have two options:

1) have an exporter for android and one for iPhone that export the excel data to the native supported iPhone/Android strings (.strings and .xml files )

2) do not use the native formats and always export the files into the same custom format and do everything on your own in app.

I usually go for option 1

Comment: either i don't understand the second option or it is a bit ugly. My idea was the same to your first option. I just thought, there some good tools for that

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tool that can read many formats from mygengo.com. I never tried it, but it seems to handle both Android and iPhone formats and many more..

[Strings from MyGengo](http://mygengo.com/translation-solutions/iphone-android-app-translation/)